# How to Read All But the Header Row of a .CSV File?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, csv, stringreader

I need to read a .csv file into an array but I don't want the first row of the .csv file to be in the array.  How do I exclude it?

```
'Create array.
        Dim sReader As New StringReader(strBuffer)
        Dim List As New List(Of String)
    Do While sReader.Peek >= 0
        List.Add(sReader.ReadLine)
    Loop
        Dim lines As String() = List.ToArray
        sReader.Close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you just remove the first element in the list?

`List.RemoveAt(0);`

Answer (score 1):

You could also do a readline before the loop:

```
'Create array.
        Dim sReader As New StringReader(strBuffer)
        Dim List As New List(Of String)
        sReader.ReadLine
    Do While sReader.Peek >= 0
        List.Add(sReader.ReadLine)
    Loop
        Dim lines As String() = List.ToArray
        sReader.Close()
```

You could simplify your code alot by using

```
Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllines("MycsvFile.csv")
lines.RemoveAt(0)
```